# OpenXML asp.net loop through header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, openxml

I have a 10 page document. Each page has a header and footer. The header might have two lines of text or one, with each one having a different style. What a want to do is to loop through the document. Read the header and footer of each page, put that into a `DataTable` so I can build a TOC later on. Any idea, I tried but it's not working correctly, it's not reading each page footer and skipping pages(It seems out of order and I'd like to get the values in the page order since it seems to skip the first page until the last iteration).

Help would be appreciated. JT

```
 Using wordDoc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(combineDocName, True)
        For Each Head As HeaderPart In wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts
            For Each currentParagraph As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph In Head.RootElement.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph)()
          Dim p As ParagraphProperties = currentParagraph.Elements(Of ParagraphProperties)().First()
                If p.Count > 0 Then
                    If (p.ParagraphStyleId IsNot Nothing) Then
                        If p.ParagraphStyleId.Val.ToString() = "HeaderBar" Then
                            For Each currentText As Text In Head.RootElement.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()
                                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(keepHeaderM)) Then
                                    HeaderBarTxt = currentText.Text.Trim()
                                ElseIf keepHeaderM <> currentText.Text.Trim() Then
                                    HeaderBarTxt = currentText.Text.Trim()
                                End If
                            Next
                        ElseIf p.ParagraphStyleId.Val.ToString() = "NavigationBar" Then
                            For Each currentText As Text In Head.RootElement.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()
                                iCount = currentText.Text.Split(":").Length - 1
                                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(keepHeaderM)) Then
                                    HeaderTxt = currentText.Text.Trim()
                                ElseIf keepHeaderM <> currentText.Text.Trim() Then
                                    HeaderTxt = currentText.Text.Trim()
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
             Next
          Next
           For Each foot As FooterPart In wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts
                For Each currentParagraph2 As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph In foot.RootElement.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph)()
                    If currentParagraph2.Count > 0 Then
                        For Each currentText2 As Text In foot.RootElement.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()
                            Dim strTemp As String = currentText2.Text
                            If strTemp.IndexOf("-") <> -1 Then
                                FooterTxt = currentText2.Text.Trim()

                            End If
                        Next
                    End If

                Next
            Next
 end using
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is the format of the document?

Comment: What I find is when you loop it doesn't do it in order what I need is how to loop through the pages in order...I tried the following but I still get the 3rd page first and the first page last for some reason. How do I loop through this in order?

Answer (score 0):

If you have different headers and footers in the Word file, then I'm assuming that there are multiple sections in your Word document.

You'll have to iterate through these sections and then read the footers and headers in the sections and then save them somewhere in a DataTable.

Coming to the question of creating a TOC.

What you could do is create a separate word document with a TOC created manually say TOC.docx.
Now when you want to add the TOC, you create a copy of TOC.docx and then merge this file with document in which you want to TOC.
Don't forget to set the auto update to true in the settings of the merged document.

```
<w:updateFields w:val="true" />
```